# How to copy files from Window to a network (Linux) drive without root of that drive

Tags: linux, windows, sshfs

I need to copy files from a Windows machine to a remote Linux host's `/opt/` dir, however, I don't have root access to that Linux host so directly copying files to `/opt/` is not possible.

What I have now are:

- I can mount that Linux host on the Windows machine and map it as a drive, say "Z:"
- I can copy files over to myself's home folder(`/home/myaccount/`) on that Linux machine.
- I can use `sudo` on that Linux host if I login on that Linux.

So how can I copy files from my Windows to the remote Linux host's `/opt` dir? And how do I use `sudo` on the Linux host from Windows if ever possible?

Comment: Do you mean you are using samba? Or is it sshfs? And is `/opt` a mountpoint? If it is, what's the type of the filesystem mounted on it?

Comment: @TomYan I'm using sshfs to mount the Linux host and the mount point is `/`. I'm able to read all those files on there but have no permission to write to `/` and `/opt`. And I need to transfer files to there... usually, if I transfer files from another Linux I would just ssh onto it and use `sudo`, but from Windows, I found I can't do that anymore

Comment: Not possible. What’s wrong with copying the stuff elsewhere first, then moving it locally?

Comment: @DanielB Right, so later I tried to first copy files to my account `/home/myaccount` but then I have problem copying files from `/home/myaccount` to `/opt/` for same permission reason

Comment: For sshfs I think the conclusion of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701487/108618) applies regardless of the OS of the client.

Comment: @Henry You'll need to get your user account the ownership / permission / ACL that is necessary. There's no way getting around it. (An exception would be `/opt` is a mountpoint of an external drive, in which case you can "fix things" in advance on your own machine, or use the correct mount option if it's e.g. some Windows filesystem like NTFS.)

Answer (score 0):

The “recipe” for copying to privileged locations over the network is relatively simple: Put the stuff somewhere you can, then log in using SSH and use `sudo` to move it to where it should be. Don’t forget to `chown`/`chmod` as required afterwards.

Enabling writing to these locations is not a good idea. If absolutely required (because the files to copy are prohibitively large, free space is low, the destination is on a separate filesystem or whatever), create a directory in (or near) the desired location and then make it writable for your share user. After you are finished, make it read-only again.

---

`sudo` is a shell command. You can only use it from the shell (SSH or related methods). You cannot use it with a file protocol like FTP or SMB/CIFS or the like.